# Re-raise ruby exception from different place

Tags: ruby, exception

How do I make the exception reraised from `bar` in the last line look like it came from there, and not from the block? I want to see `bar` in the backtrace.

```
begin
  raise "foo"
rescue => e # yeah, i know
  $e = e # oh boy, globals
end

sleep 1 # again, i know

def bar
  raise $e
end

bar # => test.rb:2:in `<main>': foo (RuntimeError)
```

*Edit:*

The current backtrace is

```
test.rb:2:in `<main>': foo (RuntimeError)
```

what I want is (or sth similar)

```
test.rb:10:in `bar': foo (RuntimeError)
from test.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Very good question,Indeed *+1* ..

Comment: What exactly do you want to have in a backtrace? Just bar, or the original backtrace as well?

Comment: I cannot tell yet what you want, but you may consider reading more about exception in general, to see if this is the right conceptual approach.  **Please post the backtrace you are getting now, and what you want instead**

Comment: I've edited the question to include the backtrace I'm getting and the one I want. The idea behind this code is that I want to send an exception from one thread (doing network stuff) to another one (waiting for network stuff to happen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that's what you want, but you can try:

```
begin
  raise "foo"
rescue => e
  $e = e
end

sleep 1 

def get_full_stack
  caller
end

def bar
  exception = $e.dup
  exception.set_backtrace get_full_stack   
  raise exception
end
```

Comment: This works, replacing `get_full_stack` with `Kernel.caller`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the correct answer. But I decided to give it a go :-)

```
begin
  raise "foo"
rescue => e
   $e = e
end

sleep 1 

def bar    
  raise $e.class, "bar"
end

bar #=> test.rb:10:in `bar': bar (RuntimeError)
    from test.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

Second try

```
begin
  ...
end

sleep 1 

def bar  
  $e.set_backtrace(["bar"])    
  raise $e
end

bar #=> bar: foo (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question. Also, I don't want the code to know much about the exception, as it might contain more than just a string.